# Listings package split frame when the page ends

Tags: listings, framed

When I use the listings package with frame in my code the frame "breaks" when the page ends and it is open in the end of the page. I want the frame to be complete with four sides and continue in the next page again with all four frame sides complete. How can I do this? Why does the frame "breaks"?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for the listings package.

Comment: Why is this an off-topic question?

Comment: Because it is essentially a feature request for the listings package, and, as such, not really fit for a question on this site. You would be better off contacting the maintainer of `listings` directly.

Comment: You mean that there isn't already a way to do it and I must ask the maintainer to create that feature?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. As you can see by following the link in my comment above, a very similar question has already been asked here, and was never answered, so it's unlikely yours will. You should suggests this feature to the maintainer of `listings`.

Comment: @Jubobs We have a magic wand called `tcolorbox` ;)

Comment: @HarishKumar I'll retract my close vote. Perhaps you should vote to reopen http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162684/listings-frame-for-multiple-page-code and answer that one too.

Comment: @Jubobs I just did. But these two are similar and hence one of them may be marked as duplicate IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,listings}
\usepackage[textheight=2in]{geometry}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
     basicstyle=\ttfamily,
     numbers=left,
     numberstyle=\tiny,
     numbersep=5pt
 }
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,breakable}
\newtcblisting{mycode}{
      arc=0mm,
      top=0mm,
      bottom=0mm,
      left=3mm,
      right=0mm,
      width=\textwidth,
      boxrule=1pt,
      colback=blue!20,
      listing only,
      listing options={style=mystyle},
      breakable
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mycode}
abc def {

xyz




some 

again some

Some again
\end{mycode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The advantage is, with `tcolorbox`, you can do lot of customisations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will check if it solves my problem.

Comment: I tried it and it works! The only "problem" is that you have to specify how big you want the box to be although I would prefer to adjust automatically with the length of the code.

Comment: @Adam There is `hbox` option but it won't allow you to break across pages. You can try with `varwidth` and post a new question on that. :)

Comment: I think that someone can use a box as long as the page for the worst case. This seem to solve the previous problem I mentioned!

Comment: Also why there is space at the top and at the bottom of the box? How can I make it disappear?

Comment: @Adam You can adjust `top` and `bottom`.